# VB.Net How to programmatically add a control and an event handler

Tags: vb.net, events, controls

I'm creating a game using the PictureBox control and adding a MouseDown event to handle reducing the "health" value of the PictureBox.

I would like to programmatically add a new control when the initial control loses all of it's health so that I can add variance to how the new PictureBox appears, but I do not know how to add an event handler to a programmatically created control.

Update: Thanks for the help!
This is how my finished code works, if you would like to do the same.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub NewBug()
        Dim pbBug As New PictureBox With {
        .Name = "pb",
        .Width = 100,
        .Height = 100,
        .Top = 75,
        .Left = 75,
        .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
        .Image = My.Resources.bug}
        Me.Controls.Add(pbBug)

        AddHandler pbBug.MouseDown, Sub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                                    MessageBox.Show("Hello", "It Worked")
                                End Sub
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        NewBug()
    End Sub
```

Thanks,
sunnyCr

Comment: Remove `Handles MyButton.Click`, add  `Me.Controls.Add(MyButton)`

Comment: Note that, in any event handler, you can use the `sender` parameter to access the object that raised the event.  That means that, if you handle an event for multiple objects with the one method, you can determine which of those objects raised the event.

Comment: For the future, you add control to parent like <parent>.Controls.Add eg Me.Controls.Add(Picturebox), while handlers are added and removed like add hander object.type, address of method eg addhandler pbBug.MouseDown, address of TestSub()

Comment: It is odd to me that you altered the original content of your question. These comments and answer now seem like orphans

Comment: @Mr.Tripodi, Sorry, this is my first post. I wasn't quite sure on how i should do anything with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something isnt adding up. It would appear as though `Dim MyButton As New Button()` should be declared at Class scope, you should not have to declare WithEvents on local variables. Furthermore the `MyButton_Click` sub wouldnt compile if MyButton was Local to load routine. If it is declared at Class Scope then instead of `Dim MyButton As New Button` You would `WithEvents MyButton As New Button` If you want to keep it local then you could do something like this instead

```
Dim MyButton As New Button With {
     .Name = "MyButton",
     .Top = 100,
     .Left = 100,
     .Image = My.Resources.SomeImage}

Controls.Add(MyButton)

AddHandler MyButton.Click, Sub(s As Object, ev As EventArgs)
                               'Do stuff
                           End Sub
```

which is generally how I do things as this, unless I intend to remove the handler, then I will create a Sub and use AddressOf such as how you are attempting to use it.

Comment: My initial example used a button so yours did too, but I wanted to use this for a picturebox. Regardless, this fixed my problem and was something that my tutor could not figure out either; so thank you for the help!

Comment: @Mr. Tripodi Shouldn't handler be added before adding the control?

Comment: Personally I add all handles at the end of the load event

Comment: ^Well I should say at the end of whatever routine they are subject to

Answer (score 0):

You must create a class for generate a picturebox by code importing windows.system.Forms; as example you can do this, changing label for picturebox:

This is the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    class Etiqueta
    {
        private Label etiquetaHija;

        public Label EtiquetaHija { get => etiquetaHija; set => etiquetaHija = value; }

        public Etiqueta(Point posicion, Size dimensiones, string texto)
        {
            etiquetaHija = new Label();
            etiquetaHija.Size = dimensiones;
            etiquetaHija.Location = posicion;
            etiquetaHija.Text = texto;
            etiquetaHija.Click += EtiquetaHija_Click;
                   }

        private void EtiquetaHija_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Etiqueta Hija");
        }

  
    }
```

This is the code behind of the form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Etiqueta etiqueta = new Etiqueta(new Point(20, 20), new Size(100, 100), "Ejemplo de creacion de un label por codigo con manejador de eventos");
            this.Controls.Add(etiqueta.EtiquetaHija );
        }
    }
}
```